# How to track down an "Uncaught Error: Could not find module `@ember/component`" error?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've updated the addon [`ember-attacher`](https://github.com/kybishop/ember-attacher) in my ember project from `v0.11.4` to `v0.13.0` and now i'm getting the below error:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `@ember/component` imported from `@ember-decorators/argument/-debug/validated-component`
at missingModule (loader.js:247)
at findModule (loader.js:258)
at Module.findDeps (loader.js:168)
at findModule (loader.js:262)
at Module.findDeps (loader.js:168)
at findModule (loader.js:262)
at Module.findDeps (loader.js:168)
at findModule (loader.js:262)
at Module.findDeps (loader.js:168)
at findModule (loader.js:262)
```

I think there is some problem with `@ember/component` not available/loaded yet, when [`ember-decorators`](https://github.com/ember-decorators/ember-decorators) wants to use it. But i don't know how to track down what's causing the issue.

There are no other problems/execptions besides the module error (only some caught ones from babel-polyfill).

Deleting `node_modules` for a fresh dependencies installation didn't changed anything. It also happens in both, production and delevopment build.

I also tried to reproduce the same issue in a fresh ember-cli project, but didn't managed to do so (created an empty project, added all the same dependencies and config settings, created a test page showing an ember-attacher tooltip and popover).

So it must be a special case, but i don't know what causes the problem.

How can i get more insight about why the error occurs? Are there any hints available from debbuging, which i didn't recognized?

I can't provide a repository of our project, but may be able to provide individual code parts, if specific information is needed.

ember -v --verbose:

```
ember-cli: 2.17.0
http_parser: 2.7.0
node: 8.9.1
v8: 6.1.534.47
uv: 1.15.0
zlib: 1.2.11
ares: 1.10.1-DEV
modules: 57
nghttp2: 1.25.0
openssl: 1.0.2m
icu: 59.1
unicode: 9.0
cldr: 31.0.1
tz: 2017b
os: win32 x64
```

Dependencies:

```
"broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.6.0",
"ember-ajax": "^3.0.0",
"ember-attacher": "^0.13.0",
"ember-chrome-devtools": "^0.2.0",
"ember-cli": "~2.17.0",
"ember-cli-app-version": "^3.1.3",
"ember-cli-autoprefixer": "^0.8.1",
"ember-cli-babel": "^6.10.0",
"ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^2.1.0",
"ember-cli-eslint": "^4.2.2",
"ember-cli-htmlbars": "^2.0.3",
"ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^1.0.2",
"ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.7.0",
"ember-cli-moment-shim": "^3.5.0",
"ember-cli-qunit": "^4.1.1",
"ember-cli-sass": "^7.1.2",
"ember-cli-shims": "^1.2.0",
"ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.1",
"ember-cli-string-helpers": "1.5.0",
"ember-cli-uglify": "^2.0.0",
"ember-cli-windows-addon": "^1.3.1",
"ember-cli-yuidoc": "^0.8.8",
"ember-composable-helpers": "^2.0.3",
"ember-cp-validations": "^3.5.1",
"ember-crumbly": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
"ember-data": "~2.17.0",
"ember-debounced-properties": "0.0.5",
"ember-drag-drop": "^0.4.6",
"ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.0",
"ember-intl": "^2.31.1",
"ember-intl-cp-validations": "^3.0.1",
"ember-load-initializers": "^1.0.0",
"ember-md5": "^1.0.1",
"ember-moment": "^7.5.0",
"ember-paper": "~1.0.0-beta.3",
"ember-pikaday": "^2.2.3",
"ember-pouch": "^4.3.0",
"ember-promise-helpers": "^1.0.3",
"ember-resolver": "^4.5.0",
"ember-responsive": "^2.0.5",
"ember-route-action-helper": "^2.0.6",
"ember-shepherd": "^2.8.0",
"ember-simple-auth": "^1.4.0",
"ember-source": "~2.17.0",
"ember-tether": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
"ember-timepicker": "^0.2.0",
"ember-transition-helper": "^0.0.6",
"ember-truth-helpers": "^2.0.0",
"ember-user-activity": "^0.9.0",
"ember-uuid": "^1.0.0",
"ember-wormhole": "^0.5.3",
"eslint": "^4.12.1",
"eslint-plugin-ember": "^5.0.1",
"loader.js": "^4.6.0",
"paper-time-picker": "^0.1.15",
"pouchdb-authentication": "^0.5.5",
"string_score": "^0.1.22",
"yuidoc-ember-theme": "^1.4.0"
```

Any help or tipps are appreciated. Already thanks for taking the time to read my post.

Comment: I faced something similar as one of the addons we use upgraded. Since we were not catching up on the latest Ember, we temporarily solved the problem with decreasing version of the addon. I know this does not help you in the long term (to keep track with the addon you will have to upgrade main deps too) but better than nothing

Comment: All in all, I debug such problems using browser dev tool, setting up a breakpoint and tracking down module name or anything that can bring me to the source of the problem

Comment: @Pavol Thanks for your answer. For now we can stick to the older addon, as you suggested. But i'd like to upgrade to benefit from the addons improvements. I tried to track down the issue via Chrome debugger, but i got lost as it seems to be deep in embers or babels toolchain.